# Vertically align using margin-top and jQuery

Tags: jquery, margin, vertical-alignment

I've got a div that needs to be vertically centered by changing the margin-top with css. **This div will be dynamic and I want to avoid `position:absolute`**.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 

    <div class="exp">
        <p>content</p>

    <p>content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var cHeight = $('.container').height();
var expHeight - $('.exp').height();

$('.exp').css({"margin-top":10});
```

However, I am unaware of the logic used to center a div using the parent height, let alone how to apply that into jQuery.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/t2kUG/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var cHeight = $('.container').height();
var expHeight = $('.exp').height();
$('.exp').css({"margin-top": (cHeight-expHeight)/2+"px"});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HEEUJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last jQuery line to this:

`$(".exp").css("margin-top",cHeight/2 - expHeight/2);`

Also, there's a syntax error.

`var expHeight = $(".exp").height();`

should be

`var expHeight = $(".exp").height();`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a syntax error when declaring your var expHeight (you used - instead of = ).

You need to take the measurement of the outer container (cHeight) and subtract the inner content height (expHeight). That gives you the height difference, but you only need to apply this to one side of the element (margin-top) so you divide that number by 2. Then you will set this as the margin-top.

```
var cHeight = $('.container').height();
var expHeight = $('.exp').height(); // Fix syntax error
var mTop = (cHeight - expHeight) / 2; // subtract inner from outer and divide by 2

$('.exp').css({ marginTop: mTop  }); // set CSS
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t2kUG/1/